# Css Minimizer Plugin: postcss-svgo: Error: Plugin name should be specified [Gatsby]

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass, gatsby, postcss

### Description

I cannot get Webpack, Sass, PostCss whatever it is, to work with me.... Can't find anything in the docs or on google whatsoever. Since migrating to Gatsby v3 I have multiple issues, this is one of them...

#### Actual result

[image]

#### Environment

I use the default `gatsby-plugin-sass`, no extra webpack.

Thanks in advance!

```
  System:
    OS: macOS 11.3.1
    CPU: (16) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 15.14.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v15.14.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 7.14.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v15.14.0/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 90.0.4430.212
    Safari: 14.1
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^3.5.1 => 3.5.1 
    gatsby-plugin-canonical-urls: ^3.5.0 => 3.5.0 
    gatsby-plugin-catch-links: ^3.5.0 => 3.5.0 
    gatsby-plugin-disqus: ^1.2.2 => 1.2.2 
    gatsby-plugin-eslint: ^3.0.0 => 3.0.0 
    gatsby-plugin-feed: ^3.5.0 => 3.5.0 
    gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager: ^3.5.0 => 3.5.0 
    gatsby-plugin-image: ^1.5.0 => 1.5.0 
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^3.5.0 => 3.5.0 
    gatsby-plugin-netlify: ^3.5.0 => 3.5.0 
    gatsby-plugin-nprogress: ^3.5.0 => 3.5.0 
    gatsby-plugin-offline: ^4.5.1 => 4.5.1 
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^4.5.0 => 4.5.0 
    gatsby-plugin-robots-txt: ^1.6.2 => 1.6.2 
    gatsby-plugin-sass: ^4.5.0 => 4.5.0 
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^3.5.0 => 3.5.0 
    gatsby-plugin-sitemap: ^4.1.0 => 4.1.0 
    gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll: ^1.2.0 => 1.2.0 
    gatsby-remark-images: ^5.2.1 => 5.2.1 
    gatsby-remark-images-contentful: ^4.2.1 => 4.2.1 
    gatsby-remark-relative-images: ^2.0.2 => 2.0.2 
    gatsby-source-contentful: ^5.5.0 => 5.5.0 
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^3.5.0 => 3.5.0 
    gatsby-transformer-remark: ^4.2.0 => 4.2.0 
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^3.5.0 => 3.5.0 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 3.5.0
```

Comment: Even with this error your build should work fine. These are more or less warnings that indicate there is issues with optimizing the packages. The build command puts the app together. After your build is finished you can use `gatsby serve` to run the app.

Comment: What happens when you run `gatsby develop`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/31509) you can bypass the issue by upgrading Node to `v16`. Since you are currently in the `15.14` (which is not either an LTS) you should be able to upgrade it without much troubles.

Remove your `package-lock.json` (or `yarn.lock`), your `.cache` folder, and run a fresh install.

Alternatively, you can downgrade to the current LTS Node version (`14.17.0`) which also seems bug-free.

References:

- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/31509
- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/31566 (your post)

---

Note: this should be a temporary solution while the issue is being fixed.

Comment: Its still not solved thoo, given me still the same errors as the first pic above..

Comment: Please provide details about what have you tried so far and the output

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. Updated nodeJS using brew, removed node_modules and ran `gatsby clean` I reinstalled node modules and ran `gatsby build`. The warning no longer shows up during the build process.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not fix the issue on Vercel because they limit the node version to 14.x.